# Symfony 5 : Authentication non persistent

Tags: symfony, authentication, symfony5

I'm using Symfony 5 and trying to authenticate a user manually. For this, I have the following code :

```
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, "main", $user->getRoles());
$this->get("security.token_storage")->setToken($token);
$session->set("_security_main", serialize($token));

$loginEvent = new InteractiveLoginEvent($request, $token);
$eventDispatcher->dispatch($loginEvent);
```

When my form is submitted, my user is authenticated.

[User authenticated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNEnN.png)

But when I refresh the page or navigate on the website, I have an exception (Notice: Undefined index: 0) :

[The exception after refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDtMA.png)

And my user isn't connected anymore.

[My auth token with the exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wP3tu.png)

When I refresh my page one more time, I'm logged as Anonymous.

[My user logged as Anon.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pN4P0.png)

Can you help me please ?
I can share more code if needed.

Answer (score 1):

I found my error.

I deleted the property $id from my User.

That's why Doctrine can't retrieve the user in database.